# Django - how to use a template tag within a url

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template tag named 'string_after' that I want to use within a URL. however I cant find anywhere what the syntax would be to use the tag within a URL?

I would use the tag as such

```
{% string_after type.site_type 'd' %}
```

which I tried to put inside the url but it is just seen as another url variable instead of the function

```
<li><a href="{% url 'sites:site_list' 'all' string_after type.site_type 'd' %}"> %}">{{ type.site_type }}</a></li>
```

Does anybody know the correct syntax?

Thanks

Comment: What is the templatetag doing? you can generate the the value produced by the templatetag and feed the value to the url instead of writing the templatetag code inside the url tag. That will not work.

Comment: Seems like this should be a filter, not a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed one tag inside another like that.

What you can do is save the output of one tag as a variable and then use it in the other:

```
{% string_after type.site_type 'd' as string_to_use %}
```

Then:

```
{% url 'sites:site_list' 'all' string_to_use %}
```

This assumes that `string_after` is a [`simple_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).